# Create fullscreen non- modal view controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create fullscreen views in my iOS application which transition between themselves with button tap. Since, I present the full screen view as a modal, I need to first dismiss the previous view and present the new view. This is the code, I am using for transition:

```
previousViewController.dismiss(animated: false) {
            newViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
            rootViewController.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

This creates a flickering on UI, since during the transition my background view is displayed.

So, I want to first present the new controller and then hide (dismiss) the previous one. Is there a way to achieve this with full screen views? Any pointers will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the Storyboard you can follow like this:

1.[image]

2.
[image]

Comment: I am not using storyboard but transitioning through swift code. I see you are changing the transition to Automatic, wont it prevent being full screen, which is my essential requirement?